# How to add LinkedIn and Xing link on a Modern CV

Tags: moderncv

I am using a moderncv template from [here](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/moderncv-cv-and-cover-letter). I tried adding the LinkedIn link using

```
\social[linkedin]{john.doe}
```

It is not producing the desire output. The reason being the definition for `\social[linkedin]` is missing in the `.cls` and `.sty` files. Can someone please help me add these LinkedIn and Xing links in this template?

Comment: `fontawesome5` package have all the icons you needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example to use `fontawesome5` and `hyperref` package to type them in the document. Or You could also add them in the center of footer using `fancyhdr` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot[c]{\parbox{10cm}{\centering
$\bullet$\quad\faLinkedinIn\space\href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/john.doe}{john.doe}
\qquad$\bullet$\quad\faXing\space\href{www.xing.com/profile/john.doe}{john.doe}
\qquad$\bullet$\quad\faXing\space\href{www.xing.com/profile/john.doe}{john.doe}\\[10pt]
\qquad$\bullet$\quad\faTwitter\space\href{www.twitter.com/jdoe}{jdoe}
\qquad$\bullet$\quad\faGithub\space\href{www.github.com/jdoe}{jdoe}
}}
\fancyfoot[r]{\parbox{1cm}{\thepage}}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\faLinkedinIn\space\href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/john.doe}{john.doe}

\faXing\space\href{www.xing.com/profile/john.doe}{john.doe}

\faTwitter\space\href{www.twitter.com/jdoe}{jdoe}

\faGithub\space\href{www.github.com/jdoe}{jdoe}
\end{document}
```

[image]